# Firebase Firestore Dynamic Data Request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get and set some data from firebase based off of the current month.

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

const date = new Date()
const currentMonth = monthNames[date.getMonth()] 

location.airTemp = doc.data().currentMonth.airTemp
```

In the database each location has a month object .. ie April: {airTemp: 34 }, May: { airTemp: 32 }, etc.

It works if I just substitute currentMonth with a specific month but not dynamically.  Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **square bracket [notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)**, as follows:

```
    var db = firebase.firestore()

    db.collection('Collection_Id').doc('Doc_Id').get().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]

            const date = new Date()
            const currentMonth = monthNames[date.getMonth()]
            location.airTemp = doc.data()[currentMonth].airTemp

        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!")
        }
    });
```